# Bigquery - Grouping by an array and summing

Tags: google-bigquery

Say I have these 2 tables, and I want the third table as the output (left joining on the `animal`, array on the `campaigns`).

```
    animal     sound  spend clicks      animal  campaign
    +---------+------+---+---+          +-----+-----------+      
    | cat     | meow | 1 | 2 |          | cat | campaign1 |      
    +---------+------+---+---+          +-----+-----------+      
    | cat     | hss  | 2 | 4 |          | cat | campaign2 |      
    +---------+------+---+---+          +-----+-----------+      
    | dog     | woof | 3 | 6 |          | dog | campaign3 |      
    +---------+------+---+---+          +-----+-----------+      
    | bear    | roar | 4 | 8 |          | pig | campaign4 |      
    +---------+------+---+---+          +-----+-----------+    

    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
    | cat     | meow | 1 | 2 | [campaign1, campaign2] |
    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
    | cat     | hss  | 2 | 4 | [campaign1, campaign2] |
    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
    | dog     | woof | 3 | 6 | [campaign3]            |
    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
    | bear    | roar | 4 | 8 | []                     |
    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
```

This query duplicates the numbers (which makes it incorrect):

```
    WITH X AS (
    SELECT  "campaign2" AS campaign, "cat" AS animal,
    UNION ALL SELECT "campaign1", "cat"
    UNION ALL SELECT "campaign3" AS X, "dog" AS animal
    UNION ALL SELECT "campaign4" AS X, "pig"
    ),

    Z AS (
    SELECT "cat" AS animal, "meow" AS noise, 1 AS spend, 2 AS clicks
    UNION ALL SELECT "cat", "hss", 2, 4
    UNION ALL SELECT "dog", "woof", 3, 6
    UNION ALL SELECT "bear", "roar", 4, 8
    )
    SELECT Z.animal, noise, SUM(spend) AS spend, SUM(clicks) AS clicks, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT campaign IGNORE NULLS) AS campaign
    FROM Z
    LEFT JOIN X ON Z.animal = X.animal
    GROUP BY animal, noise
```

```
    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
    | cat     | meow | 2 | 4 | [campaign1, campaign2] |
    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
    | cat     | hss  | 4 | 8 | [campaign1, campaign2] |
    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
    | dog     | woof | 3 | 6 | [campaign3]            |
    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
    | bear    | roar | 4 | 8 | []                     |
    +---------+------+---+---+------------------------+
```

But this query should give the result I want, but is not possible in BigQuery

```
WITH X AS (
SELECT  "campaign2" AS campaign, "cat" AS animal,
UNION ALL SELECT "campaign1", "cat"
UNION ALL SELECT "campaign3" AS X, "dog" AS animal
UNION ALL SELECT "campaign4" AS X, "pig"
),
Y AS ( SELECT ARRAY_AGG(campaign) AS campaign, animal, 
        FROM X
        GROUP BY animal ),
Z AS (
SELECT "cat" AS animal, "meow" AS noise, 1 AS spend, 2 AS clicks
UNION ALL SELECT "cat", "hss", 2, 4
UNION ALL SELECT "dog", "woof", 3, 6
UNION ALL SELECT "bear", "roar", 4, 8
)
SELECT Z.animal, noise, SUM(spend) AS spend, SUM(clicks) AS clicks, Y.campaign
FROM Z
LEFT JOIN Y ON Z.animal = Y.animal
GROUP BY animal, noise, campaign
```

as it gives the error `Grouping by expressions of type ARRAY is not allowed at [19:25]`

Comment: It is possible to do it with TO_JSON_ARRAY, then with the next cte statement do JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY to convert it back to an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  animal, 
  noise, 
  spend, 
  clicks, 
  campaign
FROM Z
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT animal, ARRAY_AGG(campaign) AS campaign
  FROM X 
  GROUP BY animal
)
USING(animal)
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

[image]